# Inverted margins with twoside

Tags: double-sided

My document has big margins on the right side of odd pages. At the typography they told me it should be the contrary. Can anyone solve this problem? Thank you
[image]

This is the preamble to my document:

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{psd_thesis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}                                                    
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}  
\usepackage{amscd,verbatim,slashbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}                  
\usepackage{longtable}                                                                                                          
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}
\usepackage{subfigure}                                                  
\usepackage{float}                                                      
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabulary}                                                       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{rotating}                                           
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}   
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
\usepackage{lscape}                                                     
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}          
\usepackage{fancyref}                                                            
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[b5paper, total={5in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{midpage} 
\titlespacing{\section}{10pt}{\parskip}{10pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{10pt}{\parskip}{10pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{10pt}{\parskip}{10pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{9}{9}                                         
\everymath{\displaystyle}                                               
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}                                                
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\clearpage \input{Title_example.tex}                                        
\cleardoublepage
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\end{document}
```

The psd_thesis.cls is reported below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{psd_thesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{report}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % Double-spaced

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bib style

%\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}      % a package of fonts
%\usepackage{helvet}             % For Helvetica (Arial is just a bad copy of Helvetica)
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}  

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\large \scshape \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \scshape \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}  

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}% % the name{1}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{3.0\baselineskip}% % the before skip{2.5\baselineskip}%    % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}% % the name
{2}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{-\baselineskip}% % the before  skip{1.5\baselineskip}% % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\endinput
```

Comment: It is  normal: the shorter margin is the *inner* margin, because when you open a book, you see `two` inner margins. That said, you can ask `geometry` to take into account `[bindingoffset=1cm]`, for instance.

Comment: If you look at it in two sided mode in i.e. Adobe Reader, you will see, that two big margins on the inner sides dont look so well. The following generates a document like that: `\pagenumbering{gobble}
\blindtext
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage` You need the package blindtext. To compare to normal, just remove `\pagenumbering`.

Comment: @Bernard Pardon but I still don't understand. I would like the page in the example to be the page on the right side of my book. Is it possible to bind the book with margins as they are now?

Comment: It's hard to say from an image, so I've checked the dimensions.The width of B5 paper is `6.93 in`, the default for `marginparwidth + marginparsep is `45pt ~ 0.62 in`. There remains `1.31 in` for leftmargin + right margin. Binding offset can be chosen 1cm ~0.4in. Usually, the inner margin is more or less half the outer margin, so it should be something like 0.3in… The problem is: do you need margin paragraphs? If yes, add `includemp` to the geometry options. If no, add `nomarginpar`. And, in all cases, specify `bindingoffset=1cm`.

Comment: @Bernard I had chance to talk with the typography and what I have to obtain now is clear: just swapping the margins between odd and even pages, not changing their size. PS: refer also to the update in the problem description in case you have not seen it.

Thank you very much

Comment: For a single page like title page, it's simpler to use a `\newgeometry{parameters for this title page}` (for instance centering, nomarginpar), followed by a `\restoregeometry`.  Their solution means marginal notes will be on the left side of odd pages?

Comment: @Bernard I tried this solution. It works but the layout of my page change a lot, so it doesn't seem very efficient.

Then I found a POSSIBLE SOLUTION adding the lines below two switch the margins, even though it isn't guaranted whether that switching has any other unintended side-effects. Apparently the problem seems solved without arising new problems.
`\let\tmp\oddsidemargin
\let\oddsidemargin\evensidemargin
\let\evensidemargin\tmp
\reversemarginpar`

Comment: How can I exclude margin changing for odd and even pages, in order to have same margins everywhere? Thanks