# Blankpage after title, abstract, chapter etc

Tags: margins, page-numbering

I have a document in B5 format. Originally it was "twoside" with different margins on odd and even pages. 
Now I want it with same margins, so I tried to delete the command "twoside" but blank pages are not added anymore at the chapters' end.

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{psd_thesis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}                                                    
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}  
\usepackage{amscd,verbatim,slashbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}                  
\usepackage{longtable}                                                                                                          
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}
\usepackage{subfigure}                                                  
\usepackage{float}                                                      
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabulary}                                                       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{rotating}                                           
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}   
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
\usepackage{lscape}                                                     
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}          
\usepackage{fancyref}                                                            
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[b5paper, total={5in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{midpage} 
\titlespacing{\section}{10pt}{\parskip}{10pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{10pt}{\parskip}{10pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{10pt}{\parskip}{10pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{9}{9}                                         
\everymath{\displaystyle}                                               
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}                                                
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\clearpage \input{acknowledgements.tex}     \cleardoublepage
\clearpage \input{Preface.tex}  \cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\clearpage \input{Introduction.tex}         \cleardoublepage 
\clearpage \input{Ch_2.tex}         
\end{document}
```

The psd_thesis.cls is reported below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{psd_thesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{report}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % Double-spaced

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bib style

%\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}      % a package of fonts
%\usepackage{helvet}             % For Helvetica (Arial is just a bad copy of Helvetica)
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}  

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\large \scshape \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \scshape \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}  

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}% % the name{1}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{3.0\baselineskip}% % the before skip{2.5\baselineskip}%    % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}% % the name
{2}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{-\baselineskip}% % the before  skip{1.5\baselineskip}% % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\endinput
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not something with a bunch of `\input` statements nobody can use (apart from you)

Comment: try `openright` as an option to your document class. (Just random guessing; I don't know the psd_thesis class at all.)

Comment: `twoside` is for printing on both sides of a page. So, when the report is open, you see text on a left hand page and text on a right hand page. Without `twoside`, your document (presumably) is in `oneside` mode, that means, when the report is open, only the right hand pages have text. All left hand pages are completely empty and aren't numbered.

Comment: If you want to change the margins, package `geometry` would be best way to do it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer general input like '\chapter{TITLE CHAPTER 1}
\label{chap:Ch_01}
text text text text text text text text text text text....' work

Comment: @WillieWong I just added the psd_thesis in the description of the problem. Thank you

Comment: @Johannes_B The document was counting all the pages. The only problem was that it started to count from the second page but I solved this small problem. The problem still remaining is the LACK OF BLANK PAGES at the end of title, abstract, chapters etc. Thank you
PS: Instead of changing the geometry I think it could be easier to add blank pages, what do you think?

Comment: Do you want to have your document on both sides of a page, and just change the margin? Or do you want your document to be one sided?

Comment: @Johannes_B I want my document on both sides of a page with the same margins

Comment: Well then, don't remove `twoside` and instead use package `geometry`. `\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{margin=2cm}`

Comment: @Johannes_B 2cm is the margin setted now in my file?sorry but I don't know where to find it

Comment: You have to ad that to your document. Of course, 2cm is just a wild gues. I don't know your document.

Comment: @Johannes_B I wrote a document of 160 pages. I would like to avoid to change the geometry now.

Comment: But you said you want different margins. That is a change of geometry. I am completely lost now. And it is late and i am going to bed.

Comment: @Johannes_B I asid "I want my document on both sides of a page with the same margins", meaning that I want to get rid of the setting that alternate margins on the odd and even pages. Actually I did it, but blank pages at the end of the chapters missing. Good night, thank you for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B5 paper at twelve point size with enlarged leading is a guarantee for bad typesetting and, indeed, the result is among the worst I've seen. Anyway, if you *have* to use a class, why bother with changing its setup?

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{psd_thesis}

\linespread{1.5}\selectfont % the class does the wrong thing

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  textwidth=\the\textwidth,
  hratio=1:1,
  heightrounded,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[11-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what does the command "\linespread{1.5}\selectfont" do? Thank you

Comment: @Luca Almost the same as `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`, but with `\selectfont` the increased leading is made known to `geometry` for a correct computation of `heightrounded`.

Comment: Thank you. I reported the rest of the preamble. I would like to ask you if there is in your opinion any compatibility problem with your solution. Thank you very much. I'm sorry, I'm almost new with Latex.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. Then I tried using "oneside" and "\newpage{\blankpage}" at the beginning of every chapter, abstract etc in order to have a blank page, but the problem is that the page counter starts from the second page after the title page. Do you have suggestions? Thank you again

Comment: @Luca The `openright` option was missing

Comment: I'm sorry, it still doesn't work. It says "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry." and  "! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}." but it is after the preamble uncommented.

Comment: @Luca Not in my code. If yours is wrong, I can't know. Of course you shouldn't load `geometry` twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42351/discussion-between-luca-and-egreg).

Comment: [Inverted margins with twoside](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318607)